# When to sanitize and validate a form

Tags: php

**Information**

I am building a sign up form for my website. I am having trouble deciding when it is better to sanitize and validate and in which order.

**Example #1**

Should I check to see if the input is empty or not set first and then validate it?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $errors = array();

    // Check if inputs are set.
    if(!isset($_POST['user[type]']) || !empty($_POST['user[type]'])){
        $errors[] = "Please Select An Account Type.";
    }

    if(empty($errors)){
         // Validate inputs
         $type = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'type', FILTER_NUMBER_INT);
    }
}
```

But then surely I will have to check if it is empty again after validating it?

**Example #2**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $errors = array();
    $type = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'type', FILTER_NUMBER_INT);

    // Check if inputs are set.
    if(empty($type)){
        $errors[] = "Please Select An Account Type.";
    }

    if(empty($errors)){
         // continue
    }
}
```

I would expect the second option to be a better way to do this, but I am unsure. Am I thinking too much into this? Feel free to suggest other ways to approach this. Thank you.

Comment: If you are doing `!empty()` check , there's no need to perform an `isset`

Comment: Note that `!isset($_POST['user[type]']) || !empty($_POST['user[type]'])` and `!isset($type) || !empty($type)` always will be true. What this means is "if `$type` is not existing/is NULL OR if `$type` is not empty" or simply "if either the variable does not exist, or if it does exist then do this". Do you mean `if (empty($type))`?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I see, so I could remove all of the issets from this? Apart from the initial check for submit?

Comment: I'd suggest to `trim()` the input first (when a user accidently has pressed the spacebar the input should be considered as empty...)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be enough to

```
if(empty($type)){
    $errors[] = "Please Select An Account Type.";
}
```

because now the condition will happen in any case

However, the value $type = 0 will be considered a failure

Comment: Is this injunction with the filter_input before your code? EDIT: the two types are either 1 or 2. So 0 shouldnt be an issue.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Filter_input should be before your suggested code?

Answer (score 0):

For proper validation of a form, some aspects have to be taken into account, to help filter an excess of garbage input. My approach is this:

First of all, check the minimum lenght of the text. This way, you decrease the risk of getting meaningless input. Secondly, check the maximum lenght of the text; you don't want someone flooding your database with a ton of text just for fun. And thirdly, you should use regular expressions to check proper formats for the different fields (a postal code, a phone number, an e-mail) and very important, allow only characters that are required in that field, to avoid or minimize the risk of someone sending miserable cross-site injections thru the input.

```
function validate_form() {
$errors = array();
// El nombre del usuario es necesario
if (! strlen(trim($_POST['user_name']))) {
$errors[] = 'The username is required.';
}
// El nombre del usuario no debe contener caracteres problemáticos
if (preg_match('@[^a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]@', trim($_POST['user_name']))) {
$errors[] = 'The username cannot contain invalid characters.';
}
// El nombre del usuario no debe tener menos de 3 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['user_name'])) < 3) {
$errors[] = 'The username cannot have less than 3 characters long.';
}
// El nombre del usuario no debe tener más de 24 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['user_name'])) > 24) {
$errors[] = 'The username cannot have more than 24 characters long.';
}
// La contraseña es necesaria
if (! strlen(trim($_POST['password']))) {
$errors[] = 'The password is required.';
}
// La contraseña no debe contener caracteres problemáticos
if (preg_match('@[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]@', trim($_POST['password']))) {
$errors[] = 'The password cannot contain invalid characters.';
}
// La contraseña no debe tener menos de 6 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['password'])) < 6) {
$errors[] = 'The password cannot have less than 6 characters long.';
}
// La contraseña no debe tener más de 12 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['password'])) > 12) {
$errors[] = 'The password cannot have more than 12 characters long.';
}
// La contraseña debe contener letras y números
if (! preg_match('/([a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z])+/', trim($_POST['password']))) {
$errors[] = 'The password must contain letters and numbers.';
}
// Password y Password Check deben ser iguales
if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password_check']) { 
$errors[] = 'Password and Password Check do not match.';
}
// El correo electrónico es necesario
if (! strlen(trim($_POST['e_mail']))) {
$errors[] = 'The e-mail is required.';
}
// El correo electrónico no debe contener caracteres problemáticos
if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-@\.]/', trim($_POST['e_mail']))) {
$errors[] = 'The e-mail cannot contain invalid characters.';
}
// El correo electrónico no debe tener más de 64 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['e_mail'])) > 64) {
$errors[] = 'The e-mail cannot have more than 64 characters long.';
}
// El correo electrónico debe tener un formato correcto
if (! preg_match('/[^@\s]{3,}@([-a-z0-9]{3,}\.)+[a-z]{2,}/', trim($_POST['e_mail']))) {
$errors[] = 'The e-mail must have a valid format.';
}
// El país seleccionado debe ser válido
if (! array_key_exists($_POST['country'], $GLOBALS['countries'])) {
$errors[] = 'Please select a valid country.';
}
// La ciudad es necesaria
if (! strlen(trim($_POST['city']))) {
$errors[] = 'The city is required.';
}
// La ciudad no debe contener caracteres problemáticos
if (preg_match('@[^a-zA-Z\- ]@', trim($_POST['city']))) {
$errors[] = 'The city cannot contain invalid characters.';
}
// La ciudad no debe tener menos de 3 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['city'])) < 3) {
$errors[] = 'The city cannot have less than 3 characters long.';
}
// La ciudad no debe tener más de 64 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['city'])) > 64) {
$errors[] = 'The city cannot have more than 64 characters long.';
}
// El mes seleccionado debe ser válido
if (! array_key_exists($_POST['month'], $GLOBALS['months'])) {
$errors[] = 'Please select a valid month.';
}
// El día seleccionado debe ser válido
if (! array_key_exists($_POST['day'], $GLOBALS['days'])) {
$errors[] = 'Please select a valid day.';
}
// El año seleccionado debe ser válido
if (! array_key_exists($_POST['year'], $GLOBALS['years'])) {
$errors[] = 'Please select a valid year.';
}
// El nombre real del usuario es necesario
if (! strlen(trim($_POST['real_name']))) {
$errors[] = 'Your real name is required.';
}
// El nombre real del usuario no debe contener caracteres problemáticos
if (preg_match('@[^a-zA-Z\- ]@', trim($_POST['real_name']))) {
$errors[] = 'Your real name cannot contain invalid characters.';
}
// El nombre real del usuario debe tener menos de 3 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['real_name'])) < 3) {
$errors[] = 'Your real name cannot have less than 3 characters long.';
}
// El nombre real del usuario no debe tener más de 64 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['real_name'])) > 64) {
$errors[] = 'Your real name cannot have more than 64 characters long.';
}
// El número CAPTCHA introducido debe ser correcto
$captcha_num_1 = substr($_POST['captcha'], 0, 1);
$captcha_num_2 = substr($_POST['captcha'], 1, 1);
$captcha_num_3 = substr($_POST['captcha'], 2, 1);
$captcha_num_4 = substr($_POST['captcha'], 3, 1);
$captcha_num_5 = substr($_POST['captcha'], 4, 1);
if (($_SESSION['num1'] != crypt($captcha_num_1, $_SESSION['num1'])) || 
($_SESSION['num2'] != crypt($captcha_num_2, $_SESSION['num2'])) ||
($_SESSION['num3'] != crypt($captcha_num_3, $_SESSION['num3'])) ||
($_SESSION['num4'] != crypt($captcha_num_4, $_SESSION['num4'])) ||                                                                            ($_SESSION['num5'] != crypt($captcha_num_5, $_SESSION['num5']))) {
$errors[] = 'The CAPTCHA number entered is not correct.';
}
// El nombre de usuario y la dirección de e-mail deben ser únicos en la base de datos
global $db;
$sql = 'SELECT user_name, e_mail FROM users';
$q = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
while ($users = mysqli_fetch_object($q)) {
if ($users->user_name == $_POST['user_name']) {
$errors[] = 'This username already exists in the database. Please use a different one.';
}
if ($users->e_mail == $_POST['e_mail']) {
$errors[] = 'This e-mail address already exists in the database. Please use a different one.';
}
}
}
// Si hay errores, resetear el CAPTCHA
if (is_array($errors)) {                                                                             reset_captcha();
}
return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Should I be using your suggested validation before or after filter_input?

Comment: If filter_input( ) is your validation function (as it seems), then the validations that I mentioned should be inside that function. If any of them fail, the form will not sent any data.

Comment: Okay I see. What about when filter_input is used for sanitizing rather than validation? for example  'FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING'. Would that go before the validation in order to not have to validate it again after?

Comment: I do validation and sanitizing in the same function. I make no distinction between both. My validation function is just a long list of if( ) statements that use strlen( ), preg_match( ) and other needed filters to ensure that nothing dangerous is sent, and a minimal amount of garbage as well.